# Ubuntu 16 freezes after startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a dual boot Win 10 and Ubuntu 16 laptop. Windows works well but Ubuntu freezes on 2/3 start-ups. I type in my password, the desktop is shown, and after 2 sec it's completely stuck. I can't move my mouse cursor, doesn't respond to keyboard key press. So I have to force-shut and it acts weird after I try to boot it again. It doesn't boot right away when I press the power-on button. I have to let it chill and try again later.

Here are my outputs of

free -h:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            11G        2,2G        6,4G        685M        2,6G        8,0G
Swap:           11G          0B         11G
```

swapon -s:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda7                               partition   12009468    0   -1
```

ls -alt /var/crash:

```
total 55936
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 јул 31 10:09 .
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root     whoopsie        0 јул 31 10:09 .lock
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie    33096 јул 31 10:09 _sbin_auplink.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie  4008837 јул 29 09:56 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 јул 28 18:19 postgresql-9.5.0.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 јул 28 18:19 postgresql-9.5.0.upload
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   449489 јул 28 18:19 postgresql-9.5.0.crash
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 јул 28 12:40 _usr_bin_compiz.1000.uploaded
-rw-rw-r--  1 nemanja  whoopsie        0 јул 28 12:40 _usr_bin_compiz.1000.upload
-rw-r-----  1 nemanja  whoopsie 16045367 јул 28 12:40 _usr_bin_compiz.1000.crash
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 јул 26 23:44 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 јул 26 23:39 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 јул 26 23:39 _usr_sbin_NetworkManager.0.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 јул 26 23:39 _usr_sbin_NetworkManager.0.upload
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie  1324522 јул 26 23:39 _usr_sbin_NetworkManager.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 nemanja  whoopsie  1894346 јул 25 08:16 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_unity_unity-panel-service.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   472779 јул 25 08:15 _lib_systemd_systemd.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie 11468932 јул 25 08:12 _usr_share_apport_apport-gtk.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   396850 јул 25 08:12 _usr_bin_host.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 nemanja  whoopsie 21152973 јул 25 08:11 _usr_bin_gnome-software.1000.crash
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 јул 25 08:06 _sbin_auplink.0.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 јул 25 08:06 _sbin_auplink.0.upload
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root         4096 феб 15 21:43 ..
```

dmidecode -t memory:

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M471B5173EB0-YK0  
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: 1315
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: CT8G3S1339M.M16FED
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
```

as asked by @heynnema

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63197/discussion-on-question-by-nemanja-zunic-ubuntu-16-freezes-after-startup).

Comment: Status please. Inquiring minds want to know :-)

Comment: @heynnema you were right, Crucial was faulty, it's a miracle it finished one full memtest pass.

Comment: When you replace or add memory, make sure to get the same size SIMMS, and from the same manufacturer/model/type... that way it'll speed up the machine by using memory interleaving. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: ps: I've also updated my answer.

Comment: @heynnema accepted with no second thoughts! You are the only one that responded and found the problem right away, thank you, sir!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: @heynnema one more question, would you recommend 2x4gb samsung ram sticks or 1x4gb samsung and 1x8gb crucial?

Comment: Same sizes... 2x4 or 2x8 so you get the benefit of memory interleaving. Get Crucial to replace the 8G, then just buy one more...but make sure it's the correct SIMMS for your machine. Go to their home page at crucial.com and use their SIMM tool to determine the correct SIMMS for your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ls -alt /var/crash` showed that the system is very unstable.

I'm suspecting a memory problem.

`sudo dmidecode -t memory` shows that there's a 4G Samsung SIMM, and a 8G **Crucial** SIMM. A little unusual configuration... since it came that way. Memory interleaving will be disabled.

We downloaded the free memory diagnostic from http://memtest86.com, and it seems to want to shutdown the computer on multiple passes. The user is going to take the computer to the shop for further diagnosis.

**Update #1:**

Turned out to be the 8G Crucial SIMM was bad. Contact Crucial to see if it's still under warranty. If so, purchase an additional 8G RAM SIMM from them (exact same model #, assuming it's the correct one for your machine, check with them), so you'll have 16G of interleaved RAM.